# Trying to invoke custom filter results in 'error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature'

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angularjs-filter

I am attempting to invoke a custom filter from an Angular controller but I get the error:
'Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature'.

I implemented it like this on the last project I worked on so I am at a loss as to what is wrong.

The filter does not contain any logic at this point as I need to get it compiling first.

Here is the filter:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/reference.ts" />

module app {
'use strict';

/**
 * Filter models
 */
export class ModelFilter {
    public static Factory() {
        return function(input: string) {
            console.log(input);
            return input;
        }
    }
}

angular.module('app')
    .filter('modelFilter', [ModelFilter.Factory]);
}
```

And the controller where its called:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/reference.ts" />

module app {
'use strict';

interface ISearchController {
    vehicles: IVehicles;
    models: any;
    setVehicles(): void;
    updateModels(make: string): void;
}

class SearchController implements ISearchController {

    static $inject = [
        'VehicleMakeService',
        'VehicleModelService',
        '$filter'
    ];
    constructor(private vehicleMakeService: VehicleMakeService,
                private vehicleModelService: VehicleModelService,
                private $filter: ng.IFilterService,
                public vehicles: IVehicles,
                public models: any) {

        this.setVehicles();
    }

    setVehicles(): void {
        this.vehicleMakeService.getVehicles().then((data) => {
            this.vehicles = data;
        });
    }

    updateModels(make: string): void {

        var test = this.$filter('modelFilter')(make); // Error here
    }
}
angular.module('app').controller('SearchController', SearchController);
}
```

reference.ts:

```
/// <reference path="./tsd.d.ts" />

//grunt-start
/// <reference path="../app/app.config.ts" />
/// <reference path="../app/app.module.ts" />
/// <reference path="../app/app.route.ts" />
/// <reference path="../app/home/home.controller.ts" />
/// <reference path="../app/home/home.route.ts" />
/// <reference path="../app/models/vehicles.model.ts" />
/// <reference path="../app/results/results.controller.ts" />
/// <reference path="../app/results/results.route.ts" />
/// <reference path="../app/services/cars.service.ts" />
/// <reference path="../app/services/vehicles.make.service.ts" />
/// <reference path="../app/services/vehicles.models.service.ts" />
/// <reference path="../app/templates/search.controller.ts" />
/// <reference path="../app/templates/search.filter.ts" />
//grunt-end
```

tsd.d.ts:

```
/// <reference path="angularjs/angular.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="angularjs/angular-resource.d.ts" />
```

Answer (score 10):

Modified working example:

```
/// <reference path="typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts" />

module app {

    // ADDED <--- MODIFIED!
    export interface MyModelFilter extends ng.IFilterService {
        (name: 'modelFilter'): (input: string) => string;
    }

    /**
     * Filter models
     */
    export class ModelFilter {
        public static Factory() {
            return function(input: string) {
                console.log(input);
                return input;
            }
        }
    }

    angular.module('app')
        .filter('modelFilter', [ModelFilter.Factory]);
}

module app {

    class SearchController {
        constructor(private $filter: MyModelFilter) { // <--- MODIFIED!
        }

        updateModels(make: string): void {
            var test = this.$filter('modelFilter')(make);
        }
    }
    angular.module('app').controller('SearchController', SearchController);
}
```

The problem is that TypeScript uses the following [definition](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angularjs/angular.d.ts):

```
/**
 * $filter - $filterProvider - service in module ng
 *
 * Filters are used for formatting data displayed to the user.
 *
 * see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter
 */
interface IFilterService {
    (name: 'filter'): IFilterFilter;
    (name: 'currency'): IFilterCurrency;
    (name: 'number'): IFilterNumber;
    (name: 'date'): IFilterDate;
    (name: 'json'): IFilterJson;
    (name: 'lowercase'): IFilterLowercase;
    (name: 'uppercase'): IFilterUppercase;
    (name: 'limitTo'): IFilterLimitTo;
    (name: 'orderBy'): IFilterOrderBy;
    /**
     * Usage:
     * $filter(name);
     *
     * @param name Name of the filter function to retrieve
     */
    <T>(name: string): T;
}
```

for `this.$filter('modelFilter')`. It means that the last rule (i.e. `<T>(name: string): T;`) is used. Consequently, `this.$filter('modelFilter')` is of type `ng.IFilterService` and TypeScript does not know anything about your `ModelFilter`.

You can solve the problem by adding a new interface as shown in the first code listing.

You said that the original code worked in another project of yours but it seems very unlikely to me unless `reference.ts` was somehow modified.

Comment: I tried your solution but I am getting exactly the same error. FYI, reference .ts is created with grunt-ts which contains a reference to tsd.d.ts which contains the reference to angular.d.ts, so basically reference.ts contains a reference to all the ts files in the application along with the Definitely Typed files. I've updated my question to show this.

Comment: I use TypeScript 1.6.2. Anyway, you can put code from here https://pastee.org/5hfp to http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground to see that it works.

Comment: That's not the problem. I checked it.

Comment: @MartyIX your answer almost worked for me, I just had to change the interface to:
    (name: string): (input: string) => string;

Comment: @AmritKahlon: Well, you used a more general version than the OP asked for. :)

Comment: Thank you so much. Could not figure out the right syntax. Could you please share the syntax to be able to use it on the front-end, in an angular view? Would it be something like {{ vm.make | modelFilter }}... Thanks.

Comment: @user906573: Yes, that's the proper syntax. (https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09)

Comment: Thank you Martin. I added a sample below taking inspiration from your post.

Comment: Well, I think StackOverflow editors will frown upon posting of an answer that is not directly related to the question but I'm glad that you solved your problem. :)

Comment: Oops. Should I put the example as a comment instead? Would that be better?

Comment: Leave it as it is. Maybe, it will help somebody and you'll get some upvotes. If you get a downvote, you can paste here as a link to a jsfiddle or similar service as a comment. :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you see the last line of the IFilterService there is a generic type for custom filters.

```
interface IFilterService {
    (name: 'filter'): IFilterFilter;
    (name: 'currency'): IFilterCurrency;
    (name: 'number'): IFilterNumber;
    (name: 'date'): IFilterDate;
    (name: 'json'): IFilterJson;
    (name: 'lowercase'): IFilterLowercase;
    (name: 'uppercase'): IFilterUppercase;
    (name: 'limitTo'): IFilterLimitTo;
    (name: 'orderBy'): IFilterOrderBy;
    /**
     * Usage:
     * $filter(name);
     *
     * @param name Name of the filter function to retrieve
     */
    <T>(name: string): T; 
}
```

As the error suggests, your custom filter has no call signature. So you can create an interface for your filter which includes a call signature:

```html
export interface MyModelFilter {
    (input: string): string;
}
```

And then when you call your filter you can use the IFilterService's generic type to attribute your call signature to your custom filter

```html
updateModels(make: string): void {
     var test = this.$filter<MyModelFilter>('modelFilter')(make);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to share a similar example using the Moment library to format dates either in a controller or in the front end.

```
export interface IMomentFilter extends ng.IFilterService {
    (name: 'momentFilter'): (dateString: string, format: string) => string;
}

export class MomentFilter {
    public static Factory() {
        return function (dateString: string, format: string) {
            return moment(dateString).format(format);
        }
    }
}
```

This is how it can be used in the controller formatting a date using the ag-grid cellRenderer:

```
var columnDefs = [
{
    headerName: "Reported Date", 
    field: "reportedDate", 
    cellRenderer: function (params) 
    {
        return $filter('momentFilter')(params.value, "MM/DD/YYYY");
    }
}];
```

This is how it can be used on the front-end:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">Created Date:
    <label class="field">
    <label class="field">{{vm.model.reportedDate| momentFilter:'MM/DD/YYYY' }}</label>
    </label>
</div>
```

I hope this helps. Thanks a lot for the original post. I was really scratching my head to get the right syntax using the IFilterService interface.