# TypeScript + Angular 1 + Filter: Assigning types

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have the following filter in my TypeScript 1.5 + AngularJS 1 project:

```
module Filters{

   export function percentage($filter:angular.IFilterService) {

        return function(input: number, decimals: number): string{
            return $filter('number')(input * 100, decimals) + '%';
        }

    }


    var app = AppModule.getModule();
    app.filter("percentage", Filters.percentage);
}
```

It suppose to change the input to the percentage value - I know, I can do it different way, but its not about the filter itself - its about assigning types to the filter.

With the following code, I get the following error during compilation:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type '{}[]'.
  Property 'length' is missing in type 'Number'.
```

Which points me to this in the typings:

```
interface IFilterService {
    /**
     * Usage:
     * $filter(name);
     *
     * @param name Name of the filter function to retrieve
     */
    (name: string): IFilterFunc;
}

interface IFilterFunc {
    <T>(array: T[], expression: string | IFilterPatternObject | IFilterPredicateFunc<T>, comparator?: IFilterComparatorFunc<T>|boolean): T[];
}
```

However, I am not quiet sure what is the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/a/33064403/99256. However, I can't reproduce your problem somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what version of typings that you are using but the definition of filter typings has been updated since in the latest 1.4+ typings.

So [definition for filter](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angularjs/angular.d.ts#L658) specifically handles the filter type you pass in with the help of overloads, it looks like this:

```
 interface IFilterService {
    (name: 'filter'): IFilterFilter;
    (name: 'currency'): IFilterCurrency;
    (name: 'number'): IFilterNumber;
    (name: 'date'): IFilterDate;
    (name: 'json'): IFilterJson;
    (name: 'lowercase'): IFilterLowercase;
    (name: 'uppercase'): IFilterUppercase;
    (name: 'limitTo'): IFilterLimitTo;
    (name: 'orderBy'): IFilterOrderBy;
    /**
     * Usage:
     * $filter(name);
     *
     * @param name Name of the filter function to retrieve
     */
    <T>(name: string): T;
}

interface IFilterNumber {
        /**
         * Formats a number as text.
         * @param number Number to format.
         * @param fractionSize Number of decimal places to round the number to. If this is not provided then the fraction size is computed from the current locale's number formatting pattern. In the case of the default locale, it will be 3.
         * @return Number rounded to decimalPlaces and places a “,” after each third digit.
         */
        (value: number|string, fractionSize?: number|string): string;
    }
```

Updgrading the angular.d.ts should resolve your issue. Looks like you have a version that has buggy Filter types that was [fixed during this merge](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/commit/21c2982f944dce0d0c517a71f561baa781b3af16).

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a shoot once I get back home :)